# Elasticsearch 2.x indices.cache.filter.size

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Elasticsearch 2.x has a new query cache mechanism.

Does it respect `indices.cache.filter.size` configuration setting from older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES 2.0 keeps a maximum of 256 filter caches in main memory. So i dont think it has any relevance now.

Answer (score 1):

No.
You can see here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-indices-cache-filter-size-be-set-dynamiclly/40079

> the setting `indices.cache.filter.size` is deprecated and you should use `indices.queries.cache.size` with 2.0 and above instead